# Change Set deploy question

Tags: deployment

I need to move an entire object (and all of its components) from one environment to another. In this case it is Production to a sandbox. Do I need to select every single component which comes up as a dependency in order for them to be deployed properly ? I'm getting Failed deployments on the receiving end where the object doesn't exist. The error is saying a certain field is missing, which I knew since this would be a whole new object for that sandbox.

I really don't want to do that because some of the dependencies are objects which are different in the sandbox, and I don't want them to change through a change set.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must satisfy all dependencies, so you'll need to include any fields or objects that are required to satisfy the deployment. You can't have your system in an inconsistent state. The alternative is to download the components via the Migration Toolkit and manually patch the file(s) until the dependency is resolved, then use the toolkit to push the changes into the Sandbox.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox - I think I'm gonna end up using Eclipse. One more question : I keep getting an error when trying to deploy one of the Page Layouts saying one of the lists is referring to an unknown custom field named RecordTypeId. I don't know where it's getting that from because there is no custom field named that - so I'm guessing it's something else that has to do w/ Record Types ... ? The object in the destination has no Record Types, but I'm including all the Record Types from the source object in my deployment. Is there some kind of trick to this ?

Comment: The record types have to deploy at the same time as everything else for it to work. RecordTypeId is only present if at least one record type exists in the organization.

Comment: Thank you sfdcfox. I figured it was something like that.